# create a weight raster for a hydrology analysis

Tags: arcgis-10.0, cartography, hydrology, arc-hydro

I determine affecting parameters of flood flow ( evaporation,vegetation,soil type, rainfall etc.). Then, I start to analysis using Arc Hydro. How do I relate among of affecting parameters? How can learn affecting percent of parameters? I dont know how I can create weight raster of parameters.

Comment: Have you looked into the weighted overlay analysis? http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/How_Weighted_Overlay_works/009z000000s1000000/